# GTK Data Capturing

Tags: multithreading, gtk3

I’m working in C on a project to capture data from a sensor and display it as part of a GUI application on the Raspberry Pi. I am using GTK 3.0, plus Cairo for graphing. I have built an application that works, but I want to make a modification to enable me to change the frequency of data capture.

Within my main code section I have a command like:-

```
gdk_threads_add_timeout (250, data_capture, widgets);
```

This all works, the data capture routine is triggered every 250mS, but I want to add functionality to the GUI to enable the user to change the speed. If I try to call this function from anywhere else other than main, it fails.

I have looked for other ways to do it, but I can’t find any examples or explanations of how I can do it.

Ideally what I would like is something like:-

```
void update_speed(button, widgets) 
   // Button to change speed has been pressed
   read speed from GUI
   update frequency
   return

int main()
   ...
   setup GUI

   set default speed

   start main GTK loop
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could achieve this?

Edit: Additional Code Snippet
(This is not the whole program, but an extract of main)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;
    GError          *err = NULL;    // holds any error that occurs within GTK

    // instantiate structure, allocating memory for it
    struct app_widgets  *widgets = g_slice_new(struct app_widgets);
   // initialise GTK library and pass it in command line parameters
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // build the gui
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "../Visual/gui/main_window.glade", &err);
    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_application_window"));

    // build the structure of widget pointers
    widgets->w_spn_dataspeed        = GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "spn_dataspeed"));
    widgets->w_spn_refreshspeed     = GTK_SPIN_BUTTON(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "spn_refreshspeed"));
    widgets->w_adj_dataspeed        = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "adj_dataspeed"));
    widgets->w_adj_refreshspeed     = GTK_ADJUSTMENT(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "adj_refreshspeed"));
    // connect the widgets to the signal handler
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, widgets);    // note: second parameter points to widgets
    g_object_unref(builder);

    // Set a timeout running to refresh the screen
    gdk_threads_add_timeout(SCREEN_REFRESH_TIMER, (GSourceFunc)screen_timer_exe, (gpointer)widgets);
    gdk_threads_add_timeout(DATA_REFRESH_TIMER, (GSourceFunc)data_timer_exe, (gpointer)widgets);



    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();
    // free up memory used by widget structure, probably not necessary as OS will
    // reclaim memory from application after it exits
    g_slice_free(struct app_widgets, widgets);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: Have you tried to do it in main thread? Function `g_idle_add` might be useful here.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My understanding of g_idle_add is that it will run tasks wen the system is idle, as I’m data capturing, I need it to be at a fixed time, hence the route I’ve taken.

Comment: I am not talking about the data capturing. I only mean the call to change timers after you click the button.

Comment: Hi Gerhardh, thanks for the response. I am now confused. My current software users   `gdk_threads_add_timeout(DATA_REFRESH_TIMER, (GSourceFunc)data_timer_exe, (gpointer)widgets);` but this fixes the update time to DATA_REFRESH_TIMER and is not adjustable. I don’t see how I can use `g_idle_add` in a similar way, do you have any examples or can you clarify a little further for me.

Comment: Maybe I missed something. Could you please add some code (real code) how you create your timer and setup the callbacks? You added `multithreading` tag but I cannot really see where you introduce any threads. Please also add how you tried to modify timer which failed.

Comment: you could try this.. get the source ID of the timeout_thread... and on button press destroy it.. and start a new one?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses. With regard to the code, the key line that creates the threads is already listed in the main question, the rest of the code in my project is creating and setting up other GUI functions and starting the main gtk loop. I have tried many different ways, but all of them fail, either at compilation or as soon as the application starts. On investigation, the documentation suggests that I can only use  gdk_threads_add_timeout in the ‘main’ loop of my program which is why I can’t figure out how to do it.

Comment: I didn't see your update. If you reply to some comment you can directly address an author of a previous comment like this: @MatthewBennett Then a notification is created for the user mentioned. Could you please add the callback functions you connect to the signal for updating speed?